# How to properly render a field from a database in a page without refreshing?

Tags: python, jquery, html, django, ajax

I am trying to display a User's name on top of a box where they enter their Employee # in a form, without having to refresh the page, for example, they enter their # and then after they click/tab onto the next field, it renders the name on top, so the user knows they've entered the correct info. This name is also stored in a separate model, so I try to retrieve it using the "id/number".

I am not too familiar with AJAX but after reading a few similar questions it seems like an AJAX request would be the most appropriate way to achieve this. I tried to make a function **get_employee_name** that returns the name of the person based on the way I saw another ajax request worked, but I'm not sure how to implement this so it displays after the # is entered.

**models.py**

```
class EmployeeWorkAreaLog(TimeStampedModel, SoftDeleteModel, models.Model):
    employee_number = models.ForeignKey(Salesman, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, help_text="Employee #", null=True, blank=False)
    work_area = models.ForeignKey(WorkArea, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=False)
    station_number = models.ForeignKey(StationNumber, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,  blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.employee_number
```

This is the model where the name is stored

**alldata/models.py**

```
class Salesman(models.Model):
    slsmn_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column='number', primary_key=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
class WarehouseForm(AppsModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EmployeeWorkAreaLog
        widgets = {
            'employee_number': ForeignKeyRawIdWidget(EmployeeWorkAreaLog._meta.get_field('employee_number').remote_field, site, attrs={'id':'employee_number_field'}),
        }
        fields = ('employee_number', 'work_area', 'station_number')
```

**views.py**

```
class EnterExitArea(CreateView):
    model = EmployeeWorkAreaLog
    template_name = "operations/enter_exit_area.html"
    form_class = WarehouseForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        emp_num = form.cleaned_data['employee_number']
        area = form.cleaned_data['work_area']
        station = form.cleaned_data['station_number']

        if 'enter_area' in self.request.POST:
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.path_info)

        elif 'leave_area' in self.request.POST:
            form.save()
            EmployeeWorkAreaLog.objects.filter(employee_number=emp_num, work_area=area, station_number=station).update(time_out=datetime.now())
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.path_info)


def get_employee_name(request):
    employee_number = request.GET.get('employee_number')
    employee = Salesman.objects.get(employee_number=employee_number)
    employee_name = employee.slsmn_name
    return employee_name
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'enter-exit-area/$', EnterExitArea.as_view(), name='enter_exit_area'),

    path('get-employee-name/<int:id>/', views.get_employee_name, name='employee_name'),
]
```

**enter_exit_area.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block main %}
    <form id="warehouseForm" action="" method="POST" novalidate >
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div>
            <h1 id='employee_name'></h1>
            <div>
                {{ form.employee_number.help_text }}
                {{ form.employee_number }}
            </div>
            <div>
                {{ form.work_area.help_text }}
                {{ form.work_area }}
            </div>
            <div>
                {{ form.station_number.help_text }}
                {{ form.station_number }}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit" name="enter_area" value="Enter">Enter Area</button>
                <button type="submit" name="leave_area" value="Leave">Leave Area</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <script>
        $("#employee_number_field").change(function () {
            var employee_number = $(this).val();
            var url = 'get-employee-name/' + employee_number;

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type:'post',
                data: {
                    'id': employee_number
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    employee_name = data;
                    $('#employee_name')[0].innerHTML = employee_name;
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
{% endblock main %}
```

**employee_name.html**

```
<h2>{{ employee_name }}</h2>
```

Comment: What is the number of characters for Employee ID? Once the length of the text box value matches that do an Ajax call & get employee name from db. Modify your on change handler - do Ajax call if length of input is as required

Comment: @PrateekKumarDalbehera It can be 4-6 digits, which is why I was thinking more of refreshing after clicking/tabbing out of the field. Most of the time the user will just scan their ID which will populate their Employee # on the screen, but the lengths vary

Comment: OK, if you want you can try onblur event as well. Or else, on change, check if length is >= 4 && <= 6. If yes, then do Ajax call for Employee name. If employee does not exist show proper error message